# MongoDB aggregate results into nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm quite new to MongoDB and I am currently facing a situation. Below are 2 sample records from the whole database that I have :

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "Record": 1,
    "Link": [ "https://wikileaks.org/plusd/cables/1979PANAMA06344_e.html" ],
    "Location": [ "USA", "PAN", "USA", "USA", "PAN" ],
    "Organization": [ "GN", "SOUTHCOM", "UCMJ", "PRC" ],
    "Date": [ "2016" ],
    "People": [ "P.Walter" ]
}
{
    "_id": 2,
    "Record": 2,
    "Link": [ "https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/11/111533_-latam-centam-brief-110822-.html" ],
    "Location": [ "NIC", "GTM", "JAM", "GTM", "PAN" ],
    "Organization": [ "CENTAM", "Calibre Mining Corporation", "STRATFOR", "Alder Resources" ],
    "Date": [ "2013" ],
    "People": [ "Daniel Ortega", "Hugo Chavez", "Paulo Gregoire" ]
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to get an output like this :

```
{
    "Country": "US",
    "Years": [
        {
            "Year": "2016",
            "Links": [ "https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/11/111533_-latam-centam-brief-110822-.html",
             "https://wikileaks.org/plusd/cables/1979PANAMA06344_e.html",
             "https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/90/9058_wax-12312008-csv-.html" ]
        },
        {
            "Year": "2013",
            "Links": [ ""https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/11/111533_-latam-centam-brief-110822-.html",
             "https://wikileaks.org/plusd/cables/1979PANAMA06344_e.html",
             "https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/90/9058_wax-12312008-csv-.html" ]
        }
    ]
"Link_Count": 6
}
    {
    "Country": "UK",
    "Years": [
        {
            "Year": "2009",
            "Links": [ "https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/11/111533_-latam-centam-brief-110822-.html",
             "https://wikileaks.org/plusd/cables/1979PANAMA06344_e.html",
             "https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/90/9058_wax-12312008-csv-.html" ]
        },
        {
            "Year": "2011",
            "Links": [ ""https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/11/111533_-latam-centam-brief-110822-.html",
             "https://wikileaks.org/plusd/cables/1979PANAMA06344_e.html"]
        }
    ]
"Link_Count": 5
}
```

I've tried to aggregate it, but I couldn't achieve what I want like I've given in the output. Here's my query :

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
"$unwind": "$Location"
},
{
    "$group" : {
        "_id": {
            "Country": "$Location",
            "Year": "$Date",
            "Links": "$Link"
        },
        Loc: {
            $addToSet: "$Location"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": "$Loc"
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$Loc",
        "Years": { "$push": {
            "Year": "$_id.Year",
            "Links": "$_id.Links"
            }
        }
    }
}
]).toArray()
```

I used $unwind and $addToSet on $Location because there are duplicates found within $Location. I'm open to any suggestions or solution so please do tell! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$Location"
}, {
    "$unwind": "$Date"
}, {
    "$unwind": "$Link"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "Country": "$Location",
            "Year": "$Date"
        },
        Links: {
            $addToSet: "$Link"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.Country",
        Years: {
            $push: {
                "Year": "$_id.Year",
                "Links": "$Links"
            }
        },
        Link_Count: { $sum: { $size: "$Links" } }
    }
}])
```

The idea is to `$unwind` all arrays to be able to `$push` link into a new array, and to count the grouped record with [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) for the last `$group` stage.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your idea! I've managed to get the output that I want using the query above. However, I would like to further ask if it's possible for me to use $addToSet on Links because I'd like to get unique links only, which the query above did not give as it gave me duplicates. I really appreciate your help and sorry in advance for troubling you so much!

Comment: See my updated answer to get unique value in `Years.Links` array and to have `Link_Count` the count of unique `Links` value for the country